# JavaScript not working, display not updating

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make coordinate converter, but there seems to be a problem, just as a prototype, I am trying to just read user input and display it as is in another div object.
Following is my code:

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function calculate(){

                var user-x = document.getElementById('rect-x').value;
                var user-y = document.getElementById('rect-y').value;
                var user-z = document.getElementById('rect-z').value;

                var divobj1 = document.getElementById('cylindrical');
                divobj1.style.display='block';
                divobj1.style.color='rgb(0,136,180)';
                divobj1.style.fontSize="xx-large";
                divobj1.innerHTML = user-x ;

                var divobj2 = document.getElementById('spherical');
                divobj2.style.display='block';
                divobj2.style.color='rgb(0,136,180)';
                divobj2.style.fontSize="xx-large";
                divobj2.innerHTML = user-y ;
            }
        </script>
```

and here is my html calling code.

HTML code:

```
    <input type="number" id="rect-x" name="rect-x" placeholder="Enter value for X:"/><br/>
                            <input type="number" id="rect-y" name="rect-y" placeholder="Enter value for Y:"/><br/>
                            <input type="number" id="rect-z" name="rect-z" placeholder="Enter value for Y:"/><br/>
                            <br/><br/>
                            <p>Please see to the right for the converted values :)</p>
                            <input type="submit" value="CONVERT" onClick="calculate()"/>
<div>
                        <p>Cylindrical Coordinate System:</p>
                        <div id="cylindrical">
                            <!-- result comes here through the script -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Spherical Coordinate System:</p>
                        <div id="spherical">
                            <!-- result comes here through the script -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

It appears to be okay, but nothing is displayed on the resulting divs.

Comment: What does your console (like firebug) say?

Comment: Dashes (`-`) are not allowed in variable names. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3155352/451969

Comment: _"Please help me out ASAP and locate the problem"_ ~  Sounds pretty demanding.

Comment: You really need to learn how to look in the error console to see what script errors are being reported.  That will save you an enormous amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console will give errors. You cant use variables like this:

```
var user-x = document.getElementById('rect-x').value;
var user-y = document.getElementById('rect-y').value;
var user-z = document.getElementById('rect-z').value;
```

The dash makes it subtract. It will try to subtract the value of x of of the value of user (like 4 - 2 )
This will work:

```
var user_x = document.getElementById('rect-x').value;
var user_y = document.getElementById('rect-y').value;
var user_z = document.getElementById('rect-z').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `-` in variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hyphens (`-`) in variable names. The interpreter is parsing it as a subtraction.

Example change to:

```
var userX = document.getElementById('rect-x').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use special characters as variable name except `$` or `_`

It works if you remove it:http://jsfiddle.net/QC7Jp/

Also you can use unicode characters, as jfriend00 suggested in the comment [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: Lots of details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names